# Unable to extract the complete message using regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to load the exceptions to a field "Exception_type" so that I can show it on my application. I have a regex which is but giving me multpile match group.What I need is the complete message on the field "Exception_type".Apprecite if you can help.

Regex :

```
(?<Exception_type>[a-zA-Z]+.*[^,]*[^ ,][^,]*$)
```

Message:

```
2016-12-22 14:06:00.4563 System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:30030
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Vinod.MyPos.MyProject.MySubProject.Vendor.Communicator.VendorSaleRequestHandler.<Send>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Vinod.MyPos.MyProject.MySubProject.Vendor.Communicator.VendorSaleRequestHandler.<Handle>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Vinod.MyPos.MyProject.MySubProject.Vendor.Communicator.VendorServiceCommunicator.<Send>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Vinod.MyPos.MyProject.MySubProject.Logging.LoggingMySubProjectChildMessageProcessor.<ProcessMessage>d__4.MoveNext() MySubProject ProcessMessage Exception : client token : [c7b9396d-b790-43f5-9561-f01c6dcdddce]
```

Comment: What d you want to achieve? What is the expected output?

Comment: I need to have the entire message from start till end (without the datestamp) in a field Exception_type

Comment: If you want the exception name with its message then try this regex: `(\w+\.)*\w+Exception: ([a-zA-Z]+\s([a-zA-Z]+\.)?)*`

Comment: Thanks: please have a look at http://rubular.com/r/0W7wGNS2yo

Comment: I need all the message in a single match-But here the regex giving multpile match group!

Comment: Then use [`(?s)^\S+\s+\S+\s+(?<Exception_type>.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/gvt9gy/1)  and get the Group 1 contents.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew perfect! cheers mate

Comment: quick help Wiktor, need to remove the GUID (can come in the middle or at the end of the exception).
Here in the example it is at the end as well..is it possible?

Comment: quick help Wiktor, need to remove the GUID (can come in the middle or at the end of the exception).
Here in the example it is at the end..is it possible to remove that?

Comment: What do you mean by a GUID? `c7b9396d-b790-43f5-9561-f01c6dcdddce`? You will have to remove it later from the result.

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
(?s)^\S+\s+\S+\s+(?<Exception_type>.*$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gvt9gy/1)

The `^\S+\s+\S+\s+` matches the first 2 non-whitespace chunks of text separated with 1+ whitespaces and the rest is *captured* into Group 1.

To remove the GUID, you will need to use a second step:

```
\b[a-fA-F0-9]{8}(?:-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}){3}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}\b
```

See the [regex  demo](https://regex101.com/r/gvt9gy/2), replace with an empty string.

Here, `\b` are word boundaries and `[a-fA-F0-9]` matches a hex char.